# Setup GitHub Webhook for Jenkins installed on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, github, amazon-ec2, webhooks

I want to set up GitHub webhook which will trigger Jenkins job. Jenkins is installed on AWS EC2. In this case I have to open Jenkins port so that Webhook will trigger Jenkins Job. I found this https://help.github.com/articles/about-github-s-ip-addresses/ link where they have mentioned GitHub IPs. Should I open all ports for this GitHub IPs? Is it secure and compliant with Best practices ? Is there any other solution which will do the same thing instead of opening ports.

Comment: You only need to open one port (the one Jenkins web is reachable on). The other option is to poll Git repo from Jenkins with cron schedule.

Comment: Yeah.. I opened only one port on which Jenkins is accessible and It worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only opened the 8080 for TCP and also UDP and used the Public DNS (IPv4) 
as Payload url:

http://ec2-XX-XXX-XX-XXX.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/github-webhook/

remember to end the url exactly with "github-webhook"

Answer (score 1):

Opening of all IP addresses might be quite dangerous. You may add to the whitelist GitHub IP ranges only, provided by the next link in "hooks" block [github meta](https://api.github.com/meta) with the 8080 port (or whichever port you are using for a Jenkins at the EC2) For now it is:

```
  "hooks": [
    "192.30.252.0/22",
    "185.199.108.0/22",
    "140.82.112.0/20"
  ]
```